# Difference between single and multi level certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

Is there a way using which we can difference between multi-level and single level certificate..  I have an application where I am allowing user to upload certificates, I want to put a check that only single level files are uploaded

Is there a command to do that??

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "single level" and "multi level" certificate?

Comment: [please see here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/) In the introduction part its explained

Comment: Certificates don't have levels. Are you talking about path lengths? If so, see [`SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-level certificate means which is signed by some other CA. Single-level certificate means certificate signed by itself which is also known as self-signed certificate.

Means, if you can check if the certificate is self-signed, then you can tell if it is single or multi-level.

To check quickly if certificate is self-signed, you can use following command:

```
 openssl verify -CAfile cert.crt cert.crt
```

Where cert.crt is your certificate in PEM format.

If it tests okay, then it is self signed and hence single level. Otherwise, multi-level.

You can also write C program to verify if your certificate is self signed or using `X509_verify` function.